# Create custom shortcut GUI/view similar to the Super + hold feature

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Ok I have seen the posts on custom shortcuts and know the `Super` key by holding it brings up a fancy list of default shortcuts. I want to for example hold `Ctrl + Super + V` and get all my Vim shortcuts or something similar with the same type of view. I don't want a text file to pop up that I need to close, just hold and it goes away when I let go. Any ideas on doing at least parts of this?

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially looking for a Ubuntu version of [CheatSheet](http://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/). I don't know of any that exists off the top of my head. Have you tried holding `Alt` while in the active app? You can fuzzy search for app-specific commands.

Comment: That looks like what Ubuntu has built in, but an installable version. Seems if I can find something similar would work if you can customize the initial short cut.